# Dropdown Javascript error: object doesn't support property or method 'matches'

Tags: javascript, jquery, methods, drop-down-menu, multiple-matches

I'm using the following JavaScript dropdown, which works perfect in all browers except the new Windows Edge.

It displays this error:

> SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'matches'

Script:

```
/* When the user clicks on the button, 
toggle between hiding and showing the dropdown content */
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!event.target.matches('.dropbtn')) {

    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Got the script from: http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_dropdown.asp which I assumed would be compatible with all platforms. Now I've already implemented it, and ran into problems in Edge.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It looks like you try to check if the click event was triggered by an object with the class dropbtn.

If you use jQuery you can do the same like this:

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (!$(event.target).hasClass('dropbtn')) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you don't use jQuery you can get the className and then check if dropbtn is one of them.

```
function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("myDropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

// Close the dropdown menu if the user clicks outside of it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  var classes = event.target.className.split(' ');
  var found = false; var i = 0;
  while (i < classes.length && !found) {
      if (classes[i]=='dropbtn') found = true;
      else ++i;
  }
  if (!found) {
    var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdown-content");
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
      var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];
      if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
        openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Marc Compte That was a big help :-)

Answer (score 5):

As it was mentioned before IE11 has partial support for it. 
Try this

```
if (!Element.prototype.matches) {

    Element.prototype.matches = Element.prototype.msMatchesSelector;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

For a cross-browser solution, look at http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/#matches_selector

```
var matches = function(el, selector) {
  return (el.matches || el.matchesSelector || el.msMatchesSelector || el.mozMatchesSelector || el.webkitMatchesSelector || el.oMatchesSelector).call(el, selector);
};

matches(el, '.my-class');
```

Answer (score 2):

According to http://caniuse.com/#search=matches EDGE has partial support with the prefix 'ms'.